# $_GET removes URL Encoded Characters, how to get the true _GET value?

Tags: php, get

1.php?test=%28004%2F58%29Gunmetal%2FCrystal+Green+Polar.+lenses

if i'll try to input

echo $_GET['test']

I'm getting

"00458GunmetalCrystal Green Polar. lenses"

What I need to get is

"%28004%2F58%29Gunmetal%2FCrystal+Green+Polar.+lenses"
or 
"(004/58)Gunmetal/Crystal Green Polar. lenses"

the PHP _GET translates all encoded chars with % and + to real value, does anybody know how to get a real value? which is %28004%2F58%29Gunmetal%2FCrystal+Green+Polar.+lenses

the "duplicate question" mark is not correct. The duplicate link is not the same at all

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's not the true GET value. What you got is the true value. Your typed value in your browser url is the urlencoded string. Just use urlencode() on the GET value if you need the urlencoded string.

Comment: urlencode() will not help since _GET cut "(" and ")"

Comment: the "duplicate question" mark is not correct. The duplicate link is not the same at all

Comment: I'm not trying to "Get URL", I'm trying to get a variable

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get the query string. But it will contain all GET variables, not just 'test'.

Comment: not good, because I got bunch of _GET, but you are right, $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] does have a true value